# Superpotential for Gaussian potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, supersymmetry, potential

so I am looking for the super potential of a Gaussian well, namely $V= -e^{-x^2/2}$, and the super potential has to satisfy the Riccati equation,$
−  W′ ( x ) +  W ( x ) = V ( x ) − a$. Somehow I couldn't find the equation to satisfy this relationship, so help and hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity to break out an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: indeed.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: @KyleKanos: possibly but I'd like to know what is understood by *super potential*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reduce it to:

$$w'-w=q(x),$$

with $q(x)=-V+a$

Then:

$$w=\frac{\int u(x)q(x)dx+C}{u(x)},$$

with $u(x)$ the integrating factor:

$$u(x)=e^{-\int dx}=e^{-x}$$

So:

$$w=e^x\int e^{-x}(-V+a)dx + Ce^x$$

$$w=e^x\int (e^{-x}e^{-x^2/2}+ae^{-x})dx+Ce^x$$

$$w=e^x\int e^{-x}e^{-x^2/2}dx+ae^x\int e^{-x}dx+Ce^x$$

$$w=e^xI-a+Ce^x$$

$$I=\int e^{-x}e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

Which is where I got stuck myself.

[(Source.)](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html)

---

**Edit:**

For the integral $I$, [DSolve returns this result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSsolve%5By%27%3De%5E%28%28-2x-x%5E2%29%2F2%29%5D).